# A Baire space with meager projections

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

> **Question.** *Is there a Baire subspace $X$ of a Tychonoff power $M^\kappa$ of some separable metrizable space $M$ such that for any countable subset $A\subset \kappa$ the projection $$X_A=\{x{\restriction}A:x\in X\subset M^\kappa\}\subset M^A$$ of $X$ onto $M^A$ in a meager (metrizable separable) space?*

Actually, I am interested in the negative answer under the assumption that the Baire space $X$ has countable spread (i.e., does not contain an uncountable discrete subspace).

Let us recall that a topological space $X$ is

$\bullet$ *meager* if $X$ can be written as a countable union of closed subsets with empty interior;

$\bullet$ *Baire* if $X$ contains no non-empty open meager subspace.

**Remark.** I admit that the answer to the Question can depend on some set-theoretic assumptions (like CH or Martin's Axiom).

Comment: I take it you want $X_A$ to be meager-in-itself, as $2^\kappa$ in $[0,1]^\kappa$ is Baire with nowhere dense projections.

Comment: @KPHart Exactly, becase of that I wrote that $X_A$ is a meager space, not a meager subset of $M^A$.